# How to reduce the size of a DataGrid row in VB

Tags: vb.net

I am using a DataGrid in VB. I have to reduce the default height of a row. How might I do this?

Comment: WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Answer (score 0):

If it's for a row you haven't inserted yet, you can do this:

```
DGV.RowTemplate.Height = 50
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowtemplate.aspx